# On Sierpinski's Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, conjectures

The statement of Sierpinski's Conjecture is 'for every integer $n>1$, there exist three integers $a,b,c$ such that $\frac{5}{n}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$

Would this conjecture be proved if we could show this for every *prime number* n ?

If this is true, how do we prove this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $p$ is prime and $n=pm$ and $5/p=1/a+1/b+1/c$ then $5/n=1/am+1/bm+1/cm.$